# MethodUnavailable(error) when shifting from Ganache to Sepolia Testnet

Tags: ether, web3.py, ganache, infura, sepolia

I previously used Ganche to deploy a solidity contract in python with web3py and it worked with given http provider & account details. But now I want to deploy the flask application that connects to this, so I created an account on Infura on the Sepolia testnet and put given link w my api key as the new provider, created a metamask account and added test Ether for Sepolia, but when I run the app now with these new values, I get the following error:

MethodUnavailable(error)
web3.exceptions.MethodUnavailable: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}

These are the lines that use the values, if it helps. The error points to the last line:

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(os.getenv('HTTPProvider')))
chain_id = int(os.getenv('chain_id'))
my_address = os.getenv('address')
private_key = os.getenv('private_key')  # should start with 0x

TraceLink = w3.eth.contract(abi=ABI, bytecode=bytecode)

# Deploy the contract
tx_hash = TraceLink.constructor().transact({
    "from": my_address,
    "gas": 6_000_000,  # Adjust the gas limit as needed
})
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Infura doesn't support eth_sendTransaction. (For it to support that, it would need to know your private key, but it's a shared public node.)

You need to either sign the transaction yourself and then send via eth_sendRawTransaction or use a provider that can hold private keys like MetaMask in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

@ruby_newbie is correct. You can sign and send the transaction but you may also have to adjust `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas` in order to have your transaction processed quicker.

```py
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(os.getenv('HTTPProvider')))
my_address = os.getenv('address')
private_key = os.getenv('private_key')  # should start with 0x

TraceLink = w3.eth.contract(abi=ABI, bytecode=bytecode)

# Deploy the contract
txn = TraceLink.constructor().buildTransaction({
    "from": my_address,
    "gas": 6_000_000,  # Adjust the gas limit as needed
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, private_key=private_key)
txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

# Wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt
txn_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(txn_hash)
```